# Prevent Overwrite of Nested Dictionary Values while Creating Dictionary in a For Loop

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am very new to Python and am trying to write a script that loops through an existing dictionary and reorganizes the data so it is in a nested dictionary. The existing dictionary is created from some code I found online that turns a row from an SQL query into a dictionary. I know this is a bit redundant, I just don't know how to edit this code to make it display what I want.

Here's the script: https://geert.vanderkelen.org/2010/fetching-rows-as-dictionaries-with-mysql-connectorpython/

Anyway, when I do this, the nested dictionary automatically overwrites previous nested dictionaries even though the dictionary key for the nested dictionary is changing. I've searched and found some other StackOverflow questions with the same problem but have not been able to find a solution for my code.

Here's my relevant code:

```
    row=curs.fetchone
    d={}
    D={}
    while row is not None:
        station=row[u'STATION']
        date_obs=row[u'DATE_OBSERVATION']
        temperature=row[u'TMPC']
        altimeter=row[u'ALTM']
        dewpoint=row[u'DWPC']
        windspeed=row[u'SPED']
        winddirection=row[u'DRCT']
        for i in ('date_obs', 'temperature', 'altimeter', 'dewpoint', 'windspeed', 'winddirection'):
            d[i]=locals()[i]
        D[station]=d
        row = curs.fetchone()
print D
```

I will get something like this (although with many more dictionary entries):

> {u'KBFI': {date_obs': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 19, 16, 56),
>   'temperature': Decimal('21.00' 'dewpoint: 'Decimal('4.00'),
>   'altimeter': Decimal('30.10'), 'windspeed': Decimal('3.00'),
>   'winddirection': Decimal('310.00')}, u'KKLS': {date_obs':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 19, 16, 56), 'temperature': Decimal('21.00'
>   'dewpoint: 'Decimal('4.00'), 'altimeter': Decimal('30.10'),
>   'windspeed': Decimal('3.00'), 'winddirection': Decimal('310.00')}}

And want something like:

> {u'KBFI': {date_obs': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 19, 16, 53),
>   'temperature': Decimal('19.00' 'dewpoint: 'Decimal('5.00'),
>   'altimeter': Decimal('30.06'), 'windspeed': Decimal('4.00'),
>   'winddirection': Decimal('270.00')}, u'KKLS': {date_obs':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 19, 16, 56), 'temperature': Decimal('21.00'
>   'dewpoint: 'Decimal('4.00'), 'altimeter': Decimal('30.10'),
>   'windspeed': Decimal('3.00'), 'winddirection': Decimal('310.00')}}

Comment: One issue I see is that the input dictionary you have is not valid.  ```date_obs``` is not in quotes, and ```Decimal('21.00'``` is not fully parenthesized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a `d` dictionary with:

```
d = {}
```

Then, in each loop, you create a new entry in your main `D` dictionary with:

```
D[station] = d
```

But each time, `d` refers to the very same dictionary. You have updated its values in each loop with `d[i] = ....`, but it still remains the same object.

So, when you print `D`, `D['KBFI']` and `D['KKLS']` refer to the same dictionary object, whose values are the ones you gave it in the last loop.

In Python parlance, we say that the `dict` objects are mutable: you can change what they contain without creating a new object.

In order to obtain the behaviour you want, you could create a new `d` in each loop:

```
while row is not None:
    station = row[u'STATION']
    # ....
    d = {}  # Here, we create a new dict
    for i in ('date_obs', 'temperature', 'altimeter', 'dewpoint', 'windspeed', 'winddirection'):
        d[i] = locals()[i]
    D[station] = d # D[station] now refers to our new dict
```

But this hack with `locals()` is really ugly... You'd rather use:

```
D={}

row = curs.fetchone
while row is not None:
    station = row[u'STATION']
    D[station] = {'date_obs': row[u'DATE_OBSERVATION'],
                  'temperature': row[u'TMPC'],
                  'altimeter': row[u'ALTM'],
                  'dewpoint': row[u'DWPC'],
                  'windspeed': row[u'SPED'],
                  'winddirection': row[u'DRCT']
                 }
    row = curs.fetchone()
print D
```

Or you could keep a table of correspondance between your key names and the field names, and rewrite your code as:

```
fields = {'date_obs': u'DATE_OBSERVATION', 'temperature': u'TMPC'} # and so on...

D={}
row = curs.fetchone
while row is not None:
    station = row[u'STATION']
    D[station] = { key: row[field] for key, field in fields.items() }
    row = curs.fetchone()
print D
```

using a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do it by creating a class and keep the dictionary having the same values as an instance variable.
The place where we need to modify the same keys so that it does not overwrite the data and creates a nested dict with same keys and updated or different values we need to create object of class and then call the instance variable and then append it to list.

So, in iteration the data wont overwrite.

Eg: class PString:

```
    def __init__(self,name,sourceColumn):
        self.pistring = {
            "name": name,
            "dataType": "string",
            "sourceColumn": sourceColumn,
            "summarizeBy": "none"
          }
            pistring = constants.PString(metadata["name"],metadata["sourceColumn"]).pistring
            power_bi_schema["model"]["tables"][0]["columns"].append(pistring)
where columns is a list in a json(power_bi_schema)
```

.

This `PString` I need to add multiple times in my list so that I can create a list of dictionaries with different name and `sourcColumn` key values but my key value was getting overwritten. So, by using it as instance variable allows us to add it in list without being overwritten.